# If statement based on a list which doesn't work - Java

Tags: java, list, dictionary

I'm trying to get this program to add to the double topPrice depending on the content of my list however I'm getting errors:

```
"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 3, Size: 3
at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
at pizzaProject.PizzaToppings.pizzaTop(PizzaToppings.java:34)
at pizzaProject.PizzaBuild.main(PizzaBuild.java:30)"
```

So my question is, how can I do this without getting the error? Also, is there any way to e.g. use a map and add up the doubles which are values from it rather than doing this simple solution?

```
List<String> currentTops = new ArrayList<String>();
double topPrice;
public void pizzaTop() {  

for(int i = 0; i<4; i++){



    if(currentTops.get(i).equals("cheese")){ 
           topPrice+=(1.0);
       } else if(currentTops.get(i).equals("sweetcorn")){
           topPrice+=(2.0);
       } else if(currentTops.get(i).equals("mushrooms")){
           topPrice+=(1.2);
       } else if(currentTops.get(i).equals("chicken")){
           topPrice+=(1.25);
       }
       else{
           System.out.println("Sorry, one or more of the entered toppings"
                + " cannot be offered.");
       }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 3 elements in `list` and asking for 4th element.

```
for(int i = 0; i<4; i++){
```

That should be

```
for(int i = 0; i<currentTops.size(); i++){
```

Since your list doesn't have 4 elements its throwing exception. Always use `size()` method, So that you doesn't worry about the loop index.

Edit:

For stop looping

```
  }
       else{
           System.out.println("Sorry, one or more of the entered toppings"
                + " cannot be offered.");
          break;
       }
```

Comment: yes that gets rid of my error however, I just get the else message printed 2 times now. How can I get this to add up?

Comment: @user3098822 Use a `break` statement in else. That stops looping furthur

Comment: @user3098822: try using `equalsIgnoreCase` instead of `equals`.

Answer (score 1):

change

```
for(int i = 0; i<4; i++){
```

as

```
for(int i = 0; i<currentTops.size(); i++){
```

or use for Each Loop

```
for(String s:currentTops){
```

here instead of `currentTops.get(i)` use `s`

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
 for(int i = 0; i<currentTops .size(); i++){
  topPrice+=currentTops .get(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `for(int i = 0; i<4; i++)` to `for(int i = 0; i<currentTops.size(); i++)` . That should do. Don't hard code the size of lists in these type of scenarios. The problem here is , your list is only has size of 3, that means you can traverse only up to 2. That is what you are missing here.

Answer (score 0):

The cause of `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException` is the `currentTops list` contains only three elements but you are accessing fourth element.

change

```
for(int i = 0; i<4; i++)
```

to

```
for(int i = 0; i<currentTops.size(); i++)
```